# react-native-image-crop-tools Not showing local device image

Tags: react-native, mobile, image-cropper

I am using react-native-image-crop-tools for CropView not showing the local device image only a blank screen is showing. Online URL is working fine image will show properly but local device image not showing. device location URL like: `/Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E38EE096-88EE-4521-BD89-8628D5B2B523/data/Containers/Data/Application/5594003F-4E1E-4D5C-BB6C-6754046728D4/Pictures/csa/Pictures/123FDJD/electric_box/110823_1917099.jpg` 
any solution regarding this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.